# How to interact with modal popup

Tags: selenium

I'm learning automation for learning purpose i'm trying to automate twitter but i'm facing error in account creation. Unable to pass the values in name filed. can somebody able to help me ?

URl : [https://mobile.twitter.com/i/flow/signup[enter](https://mobile.twitter.com/i/flow/signup%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mono3.jpg)

**My code :**

```
driver.get("https://mobile.twitter.com/");
    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@dir='auto']//*[contains(text(),'Sign up with phone or email')]")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@dir='auto']//*[contains(text(),'Name')]"))).sendKeys("abc");
```

same way i tried for email and other fields but it not working. can you help me how to we need to identify this kind of issues.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("name"))).sendKeys("abc"); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Use email instead"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("email"))).sendKeys("abc"); Select month = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@dir='auto']//*[contains(text(),'Month')]")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with `css selector :` which has a **unique entry** in `HTMLDOM`

```
a[data-testid='signupButton']
```

and using explicit waits :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[data-testid='signupButton']")));
```

A **full code** should look like this :

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://mobile.twitter.com/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[data-testid='signupButton']"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("name"))).sendKeys("abc");
```

**Output :**

[image]

**Update :**

```
Select month = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SELECTOR_1")))); 
Select day = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SELECTOR_2"))));
Select year = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SELECTOR_3"))));
month.selectByValue("10");
day.selectByValue("14");
year.selectByValue("1992");
```

Comment: same way i tried for email wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("name"))).sendKeys("abc");
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Use email instead"))).click();
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("email"))).sendKeys("abc");

Comment: try this `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("phone_number"))).sendKeys("your password");`

Comment: i want to use email instead of phone number so i want to click "Use email instead"

Comment: How do we do that manually ? You will have to click on use email instead

Comment: if we click "Use email instead" then the phone field will change to email field.

Comment: yes this xpath should work `//span[text()='Use email instead']` use it like above, in place of , `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Use email instead']"))).sendKeys("your password");`